# How to create nested array of array inside a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe `(df)` like shown below

**Input**

```
ShipID                                                                             CustomerCode  
['USWPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'USWPR04-20210429-S-00002','USWPR04-20210429-S-00006']    USWPR04
['MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002']                               MSLPR04
```

I need to create new column called `df['LinkID']` which is nested array of the above columns.

Output

**df['LinkID']**

```
[{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },
 { "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" },
 { "ShipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00006" }]

[{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },
{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" }]
```

**Final Dataframe Output**

```
ShipID                                                                             CustomerCode   link
['USWPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'USWPR04-20210429-S-00002','USWPR04-20210429-S-00006']    USWPR04    [{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" },{ "ShipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00006" }]
['MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002']                               MSLPR04    [{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" }]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: @Nk03, `ShipNumber` are last two parts of `ShipID`. For eg. USWPR04-20210429-S-00001 is `ShipID` then `ShipNumber` is 20210429-S-00001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

**STEPS:**

1. Use `eval` if required.
2. Explode the dataframe on `ShipID`.
3. Extract the `shipNumber` using `.str.split` method.
4. use `to_dict('records')` and again load this into a dataframe.
5. Use `groupby` and `agg` using `list` to transform it back to the original structure.

```
# df.ShipID = df.ShipID.apply(eval)
df2 = df.explode('ShipID')
df2['shipNumber'] = df2.ShipID.str.split('-',1).str[-1]
df2['link'] = pd.DataFrame({'link': df2.to_dict('records')})
df['link'] = df2.groupby(df2.index).agg(list)['link']
```

Comment: it works , but it makes all columns as arrays, I just want df[Link] to be array.

Comment: Your all other initial columns are array if I'm not wrong. Can you please post your complete expected output?

Comment: just `ShipId` is a array. `CustomerCode` is a normal dataframe column

Comment: @NK)3, I pasted final dataframe template

Comment: @aeapen use another df to perform the operation and then just take the link column and attach it back to the 1st dataframe that you've. I've not tested the updated code but it should work.

Comment: geeting an error ,`Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1` when do that